# Doesn't parse updated row from LinqToSQLDataClass to Database LINQ C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm building an Edit/Update system in my program using Linq in C# WPF.
My problem is that my code does submit to the LinqToSQLDatacontex but doesn't parse it through to  the actual Database.

The result of that is that the datarow is updated in Runtime but in fact isn't updated in the actual Database.

this is the code I use for Updating my rows.

```
private void dgUsers_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            item = dgUsers.SelectedItem;
            this.name = (dgUsers.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

            var query =
                from t in db.tbl_Users
                where t.Name == name
                select t;

            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                tbMoreName.Text = q.Name;
                tbMoreRights.Text = q.Rights;
                tbMoreTag.Text = q.Operatortag;
                checkMoreActive.IsChecked = q.Active;
                tbMoreCardCode.Text = q.CardCode;
            }

            var table =
                from q in db.tbl_UserProfiles
                where q.Userprofile == tbMoreRights.Text
                select q;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOPE");
        }
    }

 private void btnSaveUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (saveType)
        {


            case "Edit":
                #region save Edit User

                var edit =
                    (from t in db.tbl_Users
                     where t.Name == name
                     select t).First();

                MessageBox.Show(edit.Id.ToString() + " " + edit.Name.ToString() + " " + edit.Operatortag.ToString() + " " + edit.Rights.ToString() + " " + edit.Active.ToString());

                edit.Id = edit.Id;
                edit.Name = tbName.Text;
                edit.Operatortag = tbOperatortag.Text;
                edit.Rights = cbRights.Text;
                edit.Active = checkActive.IsChecked.Value;
                edit.CardCode = tbCardcode.Text;

                MessageBox.Show(edit.Id.ToString() + " " + edit.Name.ToString() + " " + edit.Operatortag.ToString() + " " + edit.Rights.ToString() + " " + edit.Active.ToString() + " " + edit.CardCode.ToString());

                db.SubmitChanges();

                #endregion
                saveType = "";
                break;
        }
        var refresh =
                    (from q in db.tbl_Users
                     select new { Name = q.Name, Rights = q.Rights, Operatortag = q.Operatortag, Active = q.Active, Cardcode = q.CardCode }).ToList();

        dgUsers.ItemsSource = null;
        dgUsers.ItemsSource = refresh;
        MessageBox.Show(refresh[0].ToString() + " " + refresh[1].ToString() + " " + refresh[2].ToString() + " " + refresh[3].ToString() + " " + refresh[4].ToString());
    }
```

I hope that one of you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: where are you committing your changes to the context?

Comment: @Jinish I added the commiting codes, just now